# Facebook cannot share

Tags: facebook

I have a link to share on facebook.

```
<a onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<%:title %>&amp;p[summary]=<%:summary %>&amp;p[url]=<%:url %>&amp;&p[images][0]=<%:photopath %>','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" href="javascript: void(0)"><span class="share_text"> share this car </span></a>
```

but when I share.This message occour..
**The message could not be posted to this Wall.**
Anyone know how to solve this problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [facebook share button with custom title, description, and image](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5257075/facebook-share-button-with-custom-title-description-and-image)

Answer (score 2):

Facebook sharer.php is deprecated long before.

In https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/, see the section **What happened to the old Share button?**

See this also for more info: [Facebook Sharer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118572/facebook-sharer)

Answer (score 1):

The Sharer.php function has been depreciated by Facebook. It is officially unsupported.

Use the send button instead: http://www.binkd.com/social-media/how-to-use-the-facebook-send-button/

Or Like button: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/