# facebook button customization

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api

I need change facebook share default button, I have this code

```
<a class="share" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<?php echo $eve;?>" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank"> <img src="img/fb-share.png"/></a>
```

And when I click this link browser open this page 
[image]

after share 
page open here[image]

I need when I first click `.class` open only second image and after share close window.

Comment: Something like this? [Facebook Sharer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118572/facebook-sharer)